# while saving special character data, special characters like "黃金黃" into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am facing one problem while saving registration form in database whwn ther are some special characters like "黃金黃" or oter such as Chinese worrds. These are converted to ? mars in Dabase.

i am using WCF to and from to save/fetch data from database in my web app to save registration form.
When I am running application and service on my system then its saving correctly . but when I deployed it on serevr and Running site as http://somedomain.com/register then it saving data as ? marks.

How I can resolve this problem?
Is it this on coding(c#) end or Database end (sql-server)?

Comment: What data type is the column in the database? How are you posting these to the database?

Answer (score 3):

You have to store into database using nvarchar field:
Look at [this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/guys/archive/2005/01/15/353550.aspx) about nvarchar vs varchar

Answer (score 2):

> How To save different language characters in Database as UTF-8

Simply. You do not. Save them as unicode, the database supports that. Use nvarchar, be nice with your parameters (never construct SQL without parameters) and you won't have a problem. This is a non-issue to start with.